# ¿Por qué me da el error "syntax error: unexpected end of file"?

Tags: linux, bash, condiciones, shell, shell-script

```
if [ -d lib/swig/LibskycoinNet/obj ]; then \
            rm -r lib/swig/LibskycoinNet/obj ;\
        fi \
```

Me da el error:

> /bin/bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: Empieza enganchando el código en https://www.shellcheck.net, que muestra los errores básicos. ¿Solamente tiene esto tu script? Porque el `fi \``
 no tiene mucho sentido, ¿no sería `fi` a secas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En primer lugar, debes "definir" la shell

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Por ejemplo.

El string del "if", debería ir entre "comillas"

```
if [ -d "lib/swig/LibskycoinNet/obj" ]
```

Por otro lado, los caracteres "\" no son necesarios, quedando el codigo de la siguiente forma:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -d "lib/swig/LibskycoinNet/obj" ]
then 
    rm -r lib/swig/LibskycoinNet/obj 
fi
```

Como comentario adicional, si "obj" no es un directorio, el parámetro "-r" no es necesario.